# Unable to see subscriptions with Get-AzureSubscription via Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to login to Azure AD using PowerShell with a co-administrator account. I use Connect-MsolService and I get in but I can't see any subscriptions when I use Get-AzureSubscription. At the same time, I can login in the portal (both old and new) using that account and I see it there. The issue is I need to do some things that both portals do not let me do.

Is there an issue if I created the subscription using a Microsoft account on outlook.com? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the discussion, if you're not a direct owner of the subscriptions (but have an admin role for the whole or part of the Azure infrastructure) you can use the following cmdlets to get all subscriptions and switch between them:

Get-AzureRmSubscription

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "subscription_name"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermsubscription?view=azurermps-5.0.0

This lists the available subscriptions for co-admins and contributors and can be used in Azure resource management scripts if you do not directly own the subscription but have sufficient privileges to access the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a sign in dialgoue when you run `Add-AzureAccount` from powershell?
Can you then `Get-AzureSubscription` after that?

These guides might help in ensuring all the basics work:
https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/01/25/connect-to-microsoft-azure-with-powershell.aspx
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

**Update:**

What are you trying to do after?
If you want to switch subscriptions, does the following work?:

```
Switch-AzureMode –Name AzureResourceManager
Get-AzureSubscription
```

Ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931949.aspx

Comment: Yes, I execute both commands successfully. The problem is that when I try to run New-MsolServicePrinciple it asks me to use Connect-MsolService. I use the co-admin account, not the account administrator (Microsoft account). After that, everything I create is not visible through Azure portal (old and new). I even run Select-AzureSubscription before I create the new service to make sure it goes to the proper one.

Comment: My end goal is to have an Azure AD B2C application. I need an app that allows me to CRUD users in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project via Azure graph as well as manually from the portal. The article you mentioned says that if I create it from the PowerShell, I will not be able to see the app in the portal. If I use PS, how do I set Reply URLs, logo, and Sign-on URL? I prefer to use the portal to create that but I can't set Graph permissions from the new portal. At the same time, the old Azure portal does not allow me to save any changes for the app with some weird error.

Comment: The answer the second question, the first command looks depricated (https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell) so it does not run here. The Get-Azure subscription returns the proper one now. I think Add-AzureAccount did it. The issue is, I don't know my Tenant name. I know the ID but I can't find the name. This is needed for the Graph example here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

Comment: Just to clarify, the old portal does not allow me to save changes in the app if I create it using the new portal.